# Solving equations involving the Dirac distribution of the form (x-a)T=0

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I tried to solve the equations $(x-a)T=\delta_b$ and $(x-a)T=\delta_a$, but I have some questions.

1. I have already established that $ (x-a)T=0$ $\iff$ $T=c\delta_a $

   Does this mean that the solution to $(x-a)T=S$ is $c\delta_a + T_0$ with $T_0$ being a particular solution ? (Like we do for xT=S)
2. For $(x-a)T=\delta_b$, I used the conclusion above and determined that the solution is $c\delta_a + \frac{1}{b-a}\delta_b$, since $\frac{1}{b-a}\delta_b$ is a particular solution. Is the a correct way ?
3. For $(x-a)T=\delta_a$, I'm struggling to find any particular solution. Any pointers ?

(T and S are distributions, a,b are scalars and c $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ )

EDIT: for 3), I have realised that $T_0=-\delta_a'$ is a valid particular solution. So I only need to make sure that $c\delta_a + T0$ being the solution is correct.

Thanks !

Comment: Obviously if $T=\delta_a$ then $(x-a)T=0$.  How did you show that if $(x-a)T=0$, then the only possible family of distributions is $T=c\delta_a$?

Comment: @MarkViola using the translation $\tau_a$ of a distribution, for $ \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R^n}) $ we have 

\begin{align}
<(x-a)T,\phi>&=<T,(x-a)\phi>\\
&=<T,\tau_a(x\phi_a)> \\
&=<\tau_{-a}T,x\phi_a> \\
&=<x\tau_{-a}T,\phi_a>
\end{align}

thus  $ <(x-a)T,\phi>=0 \Rightarrow x\tau_{-a}T=0  $

and since
$ 
 xS=0 \Leftrightarrow S=c\delta  $

we get $ \tau_{-a}T=c\delta $ thus $ T=c\delta_a $

Comment: If $S=c\delta$, then $xS=0$.  But how does one show that $xS=0\implies S=c\delta$?  That is, how does one know that there aren't other distributions that satisfy $xS=0$ aside from the family $c\delta$?

Comment: @MarkViola  if $ x^mu=0$ then $ u=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}c_j\delta_0^{(j)} $

Let $ \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R} 
) $.

There exists $ \chi_0 \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}
) $  such that $ \chi_0=1 $ around 0.

Taylor expansion formula:

$ \phi(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\dfrac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j +x^m \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-t)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\phi(m)(tx)dt  $



Also
\begin{align}
<u,\phi>&= <u,(1-\chi_0)\phi>+<u,\chi_0\phi> \\ 
&=<x^mu,x^{-m}(1-\chi_0)\phi>+<u,\chi_0\phi>\\
&=<u,\chi_0\phi>
\end{align}

Using the Taylor formula we get our result such that $ c_j=\dfrac{1}{j!}<u,\chi_0> $

Comment: Why do you assert that $x^{-m}(1-\chi_0 ) \phi$ is a test function.  Surely one needs more than $\chi_0(1)=0$.  Wouldn't $\chi_0$ need to have vanishing derivatives up to order $m$ at $x=0$?

Comment: @MarkViola im not sure i understand your latest reply, I just multiplied and divided by $x^m$ then switched to other side of the duality bracket. Is it not valid ?

Comment: No, it's not valid in general.  The right side of the bracket needs to be a test function.  $\frac{\chi_0 -1}{x^m}$ is not even $L^1$ unless $\chi^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n\le m$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.